# LaTex for taking notes? Clicking Enter generates a \newline?

Tags: notes, shortcut

I've just started using LaTex and I'm thinking about using it to take notes during lectures (don't know if it's a good idea to begin with).

Is there a way to use the enter button as a shortcut for \newline?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just hit "return" twice -- an all-blank line induces a paragraph break.

Comment: There is also `\obeylines`.

Comment: I use ConTeXt to take notes, and have been using LaTeX for the same task before. I strongly advise you to use an editor that uses abbrevs (Vim or Emacs do) and set an abbrev list with all your common abbrevs.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for `\obeylines`.  However, I think, in general, it would be better to get in the habit of hitting enter twice to start a new paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
this
is
a
test
$y =mx + b$ is some math
More stuff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think LaTeX isn't a great idea to take notes : Word or any program like that do the job pretty well. I would use LaTeX to get in shape your notes to finally have a lesson with a good layout.

To answer your question, LaTeX can't add new shortcuts like this, but you can use macros instead, such as `\\`, or even create a new one on your own like this :

```
\newcommand{\jump}{\newline}
```

You can read [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Commands) to have more informations.

Comment: IMHO, Word has two issues for taking notes: it is not plain text (more disk space) and you cannot use all the great tools performing search and transform on multiple files (grep, sed, awk…)